# Apply CSS styling to a particular Column in Datatable

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I am using `Datatable` in my `shiny App` as I illustrate below. I am wondering, if there is any way to apply specific `CSS styling` in a single column of `Datatable`, for example I want the 1st column to be **bold** and having specific font.

Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks,

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)   


 ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1", height = '400px')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  DF_DT = data.frame(matrix("4", nr = 20, nc = 7)); colnames(DF_DT) = LETTERS[1:7]
  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
                  DF_DT}, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(width = '350px', targets = 1, className = 'dt-center', fontSize = '50px')))
              )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      .dt-center {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    "))),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1", height = '400px')
)
```

For reference see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: Hi Aurèle, thanks for your answer. However, it is updating everything in a column, including Header. Is it possible to update only the body part of the underlying column, not the header?

Comment: @Bogaso You can select with `td.dt-center {
        font-weight: bold;
      }` for instance (I used selectorgadget to figure this out).